# Total rows in groupby then what constitute to the totals follows

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

How do i achieve this

See the table below

[image]

I want to have a total per group by then follow by other calculations

For xample, Mun and Wem are under CSS total of CSS count and sum the count percentage
and Face Value percentage

do the same thing for GOLA, just like the table in the picture below

I have tried this code below

```
refund_table<-Refund%>%
  group_by(Network, Merchant)%>%
  summarise(Transaction_count = n(), FaceValue = sum(FaceValue))%>%
  mutate("Count %" = Transaction_count/sum(Transaction_count))%>%
  mutate("Facevalue %" = FaceValue /sum(FaceValue),
    Network_refund = replace(Network_refund, duplicated(Network_refund),''))
```

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS in your question, it feels like you are shouting.

Comment: Ho Thanks Gregor ....seems I'm hearing this for the first time
correction noted

Comment: Rectified thanks

Comment: Much better, thanks! Could you share your data in a copy/pasteable format, not as a picture? It's impossible to demonstrate how code works on a picture, and hard to know where you are starting. `dput(Refund)` will make a copy/pasteable version of your `Refund` data, including all class and structure information. If it's not small, just give us a few rows, say `dput(Refund[1:5, ])`.